# Pandas Series with different lengths

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Using pandas concat function it is possible to create a series like this:

```
In[230]pd.concat({'One':pd.Series(range(3)), 'Two':pd.Series(range(4))})
Out[230]: 
One  0    0
     1    1
     2    2
Two  0    0
     1    1
     2    2
     3    3
dtype: int64
```

Is it possible to do the same without using concat method?
My best approach was:

```
a = pd.Series(range(3),range(3))
b = pd.Series(range(4),range(4))
pd.Series([a,b],index=['One','Two'])
```

But it is not the same, it outputs:

```
One    0    0
       1    1
       2    2
dtype: int64

Two    0    0
       1    1
       2    2
       3    3
dtype: int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: "Is it possible to do the same without using concat method? " but why?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This works fine:

```
data = list(range(3)) + list(range(4))
index = MultiIndex(levels=[['One', 'Two'], [0, 1, 2, 3]],
                   labels=[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3]])
pd.Series(data,index=index)
```

Comment: Isn't this just hardcoding everything? I don't think this is better than the other two answers.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you an idea of just how useful `concat` is.

```
a.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('One', v) for v in a.index])
b.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('Two', v) for v in b.index])

a.append(b)

One  0    0
     1    1
     2    2
Two  0    0
     1    1
     2    2
     3    3
dtype: int64
```

The same thing is achieved by `pd.concat([a, b])`.

Comment: For testing purposes. Woked fine, thank you very much.

Comment: @dark yeah op didn't want to use concat in their problem... :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the work for the argument `keys` in case you want to get the same output using `concat` i.e :

```
pd.concat([a,b],keys=['One','Two'])

One  0    0
     1    1
     2    2
Two  0    0
     1    1
     2    2
     3    3
dtype: int64
```